# How to Maintaing Error log of a month in C#?

Tags: c#, logging, error-handling

I am maintaing error log in c# application but on daily basis. Now I want to maintain it one a monthly basis. how to check in folder for already created file a month ago n also if not created then create it.

```
public static void WriteError(string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = "~/Error/" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yy") + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
            {
                File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
            }
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
            {
                w.WriteLine("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                //w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                string err = "Error in: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() +
                              ". Error Message:" + errorMessage;
                w.WriteLine(err);
                w.WriteLine("__________________________");
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (GlobalVar.DebugLevel == Convert.ToInt16(EnDebugLevel.Medium))
            ErrorLog.WriteError(ex.Message);
            //WriteError(ex.Message);
        }

    }

}
```

pls help me to resolve this issue.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't deal with logging yourself, there are libraries that can help you with that. Check out [log4net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net)

You could use a rolling file appender to automatically create logs for you every month.

You can configure it like so:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">      
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
<param  name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/> 
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\log4net\TestLog_%date{yyyyMM}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMM" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Then logging would be just a matter of doing:

```
public class LogTest
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogTest));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Error("an error!");
    }
}
```

To learn more about configuring it, [check out this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log4net-logging-librar)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.  It should be a comment/discussion point about alternatives to what the op is trying to do.